# How do I get a token from WebUI (uTorrent)

Tags: java, android, http-token-authentication, utorrent, webui

Right now, after setting up an account to connect with ( http://IP:8080/gui/?list=1 returns: invalid request. EDIT: Maybe it would be smart to add, that I can access the GUI if I do not enter the "API commands" like ?list=1.

After searching through the uTorrent forums, I discovered I need to add a token to the URL. Where and how do I get that token? It's supposed to be a string right? How do I get one so I can see the JSON? How do I automatically make a token, so it'd work for my Android app without having to reprogram every time? The stuff I've found elsewhere didn't help me at all.

I hope I was clear with my question.

EDIT2: I have no idea how I always find my solutions as soon as I ask the question here. https://github.com/bittorrent/webui/wiki/TokenSystem

Following this. You typed http://IP:8080/gui/token.html . Then you just clicked view-source on your browser and it returned the token. I will have to figure it out how to use this in my app still, but this question is answered.

Comment: Feel free to submit the answer as an actual answer rather than just editing your question. Doing so will make your question more useful to future visitors who have a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the answer I found as an actual answer as was suggested to me.

EDIT2: I have no idea how I always find my solutions as soon as I ask the question here. https://github.com/bittorrent/webui/wiki/TokenSystem

Following this. You typed http://IP:8080/gui/token.html . Then you just clicked view-source on your browser and it returned the token. I will have to figure it out how to use this in my app still, but this question is answered.